# load txt file to listbox using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I just cant make this load button work so that it loads the output.txt file to my listbox. im a first year 160 student with no background in coding and im trying to make this silly phone book as my first "big project" just to get kinda of an idea of what im doing and ive got everything else working besides the loading feature of my output.txt file. forgive my horrible coding im sure it could be a million times better xd

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def delete():
     select=listbox.curselection()
     index=select[0]
     listbox.delete(index)

def returnEntry(arg=None):

    fname = e1.get()
    lname = e2.get()
    number = e3.get()
    listbox.insert(END, fname+ ' ' + lname+ ' ' + number)

def save():
    list1=list(listbox.get(0,END))
    f=open("output.txt", "w")
    f.writelines(str(list1))
    f.close()

def load():
     with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
          output=f.read()



Label(win, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(win, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
Label(win, text="Phone Number").grid(row=2)

resultLabel = Label(win, text = "")
resultLabel.grid(row=4, column=1)

resultLabel1 = Label(win, text = "")
resultLabel1.grid(row=4, column=2)

resultLabel2 = Label(win, text = "")
resultLabel2.grid(row=4, column=3)


fname=StringVar()
e1 = Entry(win, textvariable=fname)

lname=StringVar()
e2 = Entry(win, textvariable=lname)

number=StringVar()
e3 = Entry(win, textvariable=number)

scrollbar=Scrollbar(win, orient=VERTICAL)

listbox=Listbox(win, selectmode=EXTENDED, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=40) 
listbox.grid(row=4, columnspan=3)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox)


b1=Button(win, text="Add", command = returnEntry)
b2=Button(win, text="Delete",  command=delete)
b3=Button(win, text="Save", command=save)
b4=Button(win, text="load", command=load)


win.bind("<Return>", returnEntry)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
b1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
b2.grid(row=3, column=1)
b3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
b4.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should be more specific than "cant make this load button". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do the opposite of `save(...` use [`f.readlines(...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline)

Comment: I just cant make this load button work so that it loads the output.txt file to my listbox.

Comment: Repeating your Question is not helpfull to solve your Problem. [Edit] your Question and show what you get using [`f.readlines(...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline)